# AWS Cloud formation : Stack creation failed due to wait handle time out

Tags: amazon-ec2, nat, internet-connection, aws-cloudformation, vpc

I am trying to launch a stack which would create a VPC(with a public and a private sub-net), a load-balancer in the public sub-net and application servers that are launched in private sub-net. The launch configuration has scripts that would download application from s3 bucket and bootstrap the servers. I am using NAT in public sub-net, to enable application servers to reach s3 services. To do all this i have made changes to a template provided on AWS website.

The problem is, the wait handle which i am using on the launch configuration times out every time, without deploying my application. but the iis is configured.

The problem seems to be in the internet connectivity. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

The template I am using can be found at https://cti-application-bucket.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation.template

Answer (score 0):

More than likely this is a permissions issue with the S3 bucket or a problem connecting to the internet, but you will need to SSH to the instance and look at the logs.

```
/var/log/cfn-init.log
```